# @IBDesignable with protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, xib

I have a UIview xib within a view controller, UIview class have two buttons with protocol function, but the protocol function never called when I press button, storyboard image like below

[image]

protocol method like below

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol TopViewDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
   @objc optional func pressRefreshButton()
   @objc optional func pressMenuButton()
}
```

UIView class

```
@IBDesignable class OnJob_Top: UIView,TopViewDelegate {

weak var delegate : TopViewDelegate? = nil

@IBAction func refreshButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.pressRefreshButton!()
}
@IBAction func menuButtonTouchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.pressMenuButton!()
    print("come come")
}
```

view controller class

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let topView = OnJob_Top()
       topView.delegate = self
   }
}
extension HomeViewController:TopViewDelegate {

   func pressMenuButton() {
       print("come") // never come here
   }

   func pressRefreshButton() {
       print("come") // never come here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
   let topView = OnJob_Top()
   topView.delegate = self
```

In the first line, you create a completely new OnJob_Top view.

In the second line, you make it the delegate.

In the third line... but there is no third line. The view vanishes in a silent puff of smoke. It is useless.

Meanwhile, the view in the storyboard never gets a delegate. So its delegate methods are never called.

Comment: I already appoint the OnJob_Top class to a UIView on the storyboard, constraints also set up, On the simulator, I can see the Xib on the storyboard. Is it not enough?

Comment: No, it’s not. Listen to what I said in my answer. When you say `OnJob_Top()` you created a new separate view; you are not referring to the view in the storyboard, the one that you see in the interface. Think.